# Activerecord Model.table_exists? does not give correct results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

When creating the actual database table in rails console, `User.table_exists?` does not give me the correct result.
But when I look into `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables` it shows that the table exists. I have to exit `rails console` and go back in before `User.table_exists?` give me the correct value. Is there some caching going on? A bug in Rails 5.2.1? Or am I missing something?

Code to reproduce:

in *terminal/bash*

```
rails generate model User name:string
rails console
```

in *rails console*

```
User.table_exists?                                =>  false  
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables              =>  []
ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2].create_table :users  => 
    -- create_table(:users)
    (0.1ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
    (1.5ms)  CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL)
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables             => ["users"]
User.table_exists?                               => false
exit
```

in *terminal/bash*

```
rails console
```

in *rails console*

```
User.table_exists?                               => true
```

using:
Ruby  2.5.0
Rails 5.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ActiveRecord::ModelSchema::ClassMethods#table_exists?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_exists-3F) is a wrapper around [`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaCache#data_source_exists?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaCache.html#method-i-data_source_exists-3F).

As the name implies, this is a cache, probably populated when the Rails app starts. If you modify the database schema the old schema will still be cached (arguably a bug or missing feature). You can reload `User`'s schema cache with [`User.reload_schema_from_cache`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reload_schema_from_cache) or possibly [`connection.schema_cache.clear_data_source_cache(Users.table_name`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaCache.html#method-i-clear_data_source_cache-21).

Comment: "arguably a bug" - _very_ arguably. How is the app to know that the schema changed? Re-read it on every request?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev In this case because `ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2].create_table` has been called.

Comment: This can invalidate only this process' cache. Other app servers and background workers keep the cache.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, that's what the question is about.

Comment: I'm just picking on the wording. Definitely not a bug, if you ask me :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev If cache knowingly returns out-of-date data, if it doesn't invalidate known stale data, it's not doing a very good job as a cache.

Comment: when looking at the documentation https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/table_exists%3F the source shows it uses  `tables.include?(table_name.to_s)`, and you will see that ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables is not cached and gives the correct information. I will use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include?('users')` to overcome this issue

Comment: @PaulVerschoor `User.table_exists?` is not calling that `table_exists?`. Its calling `ActiveRecord::ModelSchema::ClassMethods#table_exists?`. Also apidock is still using Rails 4. Use https://api.rubyonrails.org instead. Clearing the cache is much safer as all future references to the schema will work without using special work arounds.

Comment: @Schwern As you know, cache invalidation is one of the only two hard things in CS. Consider the scenario from my comment above. If your fix (`create_table` updates local cache) is implemented, other processes still run the cached schema. I would prefer consistently (and predictably) stale over that (which doesn't even guarantee anything. Another process creates another table and the first one has no idea)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev This is why we stopped calling them "bug trackers" and started calling them "issue trackers". It's an issue. There's various ways it could be resolved, including having processes watch `db/seed.rb` or other shared resource for changes. Like I said, it's arguable. But probably not in these comments.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a cache thing. I couldn't tell if a bug or not, I don't have much knowledge of rails internals but I gues it's that way by design. It's not even a common use case to create tables from within the console.

You could skip the exit > enter steps calling `reload!` on the console to reload everything though.

Comment: I'm just using `rails console` to show the behaviour.

Comment: Then your question is unclear. Are you trying to create tables somewhere else? Do you wan't to create tables in a production server on real time? when you run migrations you should always restart rails. I'm not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: yes, I want to dynamically create/drop tables under production.

Comment: I guess if you dig enough inside rails internals there must be a way to reload the database schema on demand, it's done on development with `config.cache_clases = false` so there must be a single method call to reload them.